# Angular p-triStateCheckbox change different colors for each selection

Tags: angular, primeng

My css class for the component is empty. I have this checkbox with the values: V, X and empty. I'm looking to change the colors as following: V - green, X - red, and empty - default checkbox.

```
export class EditComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  public modelForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit() {
 this.creationFormulaire();
}

private creationFormulaire() {
    this.modelForm = this.fb.group({
    liste20: new FormControl(null),
 });

}
}
```

```
export interface EditDTO{
  liste20: boolean;
}
```

```
 <div class="col-9">
          <p-triStateCheckbox formControlName="liste20"></p-triStateCheckbox>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many way, you can create 3 class with the color you wanna display for checkbox by passing the value of form control or using ngClass.

ts

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

liste20 = new FormControl();
```

html

```
<div class="col-9">
 <p-triStateCheckbox formControlName="liste20" class="{{ liste20.value }}"></p-triStateCheckbox>
</div>
```

css

```
:host >>> .V::before{
  background-color: green !important;
}

:host >>> .X-close::before{
  background-color: red !important;
}

:host >>> .empty-close::before{
  background-color: gray !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How can I create 3 classes and passing the value? What I need to put exactly in the ts file?

Comment: Can you run a basic demo of your code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) so we can help you eazy.